# C++ Refactoring basic semantic into Objective classes

Tags: c++, oop, class, refactoring

I have this simple program that computes salaries for four different worker types. It's written semantically but I want to refactor it so I can have each worker type be it's own class.

The main control of the program is in the switch statement. What I'd like to do is create a class for each worker type and then by use of appropriate setters and getters, perform the right calculations.

payroll.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

// Function Prototype
void userPrompt (void);

int main ()
{
// declare paycode and salary
int paycode; 
double salary;

// run user prompt function, input paycode
userPrompt ();
cin >> paycode;

while( paycode != -1 ) {

    //switch statement to handle user input
    switch( paycode ) {

        case 1: // manager
            cout << "Manager Selected." << endl;
            cout << "Enter Weekly Salary: ";
            // calculate manager's salary
            cin >> salary;
            cout << "Manager's pay is $" << std::fixed << setprecision( 2 ) << salary << "\n" << endl;
            break;

        case 2: // hourly worker
            double wage;
            int hours;
            cout << "Hourly worker Selected." << endl;
            cout << "Enter the hourly salary: ";
            cin >> wage;
            cout << "Enter the total hours worked: ";
            cin >> hours;
            // calculate hourly worker's pay
            // with respect to possible overtime
            if ( hours <= 40 )
                salary = hours * wage;
            else
                salary = 40.0 * wage + ( hours - 40 ) * wage * 1.5;
            cout << "Hourly worker's pay is $" << std::fixed << setprecision( 2 ) << salary << "\n" << endl;
            break;

        case 3: // commission worker
            int sales;
            cout << "Commission Worker Selected." << endl;
            cout << "Enter gross weekly sales: ";
            cin >> sales;
            // calculate commission worker's pay
            salary = sales * 0.092 + 250;
            cout << "Commission worker's pay is $" << std::fixed <<  setprecision( 2 ) << salary << "\n" << endl;
            break;

        case 4: // widget worker
            int widgets, wagePerWidget;
            cout << "Widget Worker Selected." << endl;
            cout << "Enter number of pieces: ";
            cin >> widgets;
            cout << "Enter wage per piece: ";
            cin >> wagePerWidget;
            // calculate widget worker's pay
            salary = widgets * wagePerWidget;
            cout << "Widget Worker's pay is $" << std::fixed <<  setprecision( 2 ) << salary << "\n" << endl;
            break;
    }

    // prompt user to input paycode again or exit
    cout<< "Enter paycode (-1 to end): ";
    cin >> paycode;
}

exit (0);
}

// userPrompt function declaration
void userPrompt (void)
{
// prompt user to input paycode
cout << "Enter paycode (-1 to end): ";

}
```

Comment: So what is the question here?

Comment: The operations in the switch statement, I want to move them into classes for each worker type.

Comment: So... do it? What exactly is your question?

Comment: Sorry, I should have specified... I'm a newb. I'm just looking for some helpful direction.

Comment: Just a note, you should do `while(cin >> paycode)` and inside the loop have `if (paycode == -1) break;`. This way, the looping condition reads *while reading from `cin` into `paycode` is successful, do...*. This will prevent your loop from looping indefinitely if EOF or invalid data is encountered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please review some tutorials for c++ class design if you need to learn the fundamentals of OOP. 
You will learn much more if you can answer your own question after some research.

- http://www.tenouk.com/cplusplustutorial.html
- http://www.cpp-tips.net/Simple_class_example
- [MIT OCW 6.088 Intro to C/C++](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-088-introduction-to-c-memory-management-and-c-object-oriented-programming-january-iap-2010/lecture-notes/MIT6_088IAP10_lec04.pdf)
- Youtube has some good resources too